# Finding out readability level using Coleman-Liau index using C

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a program to find out number of letters, words, and sentences. Using these values, I am using [Coleman-Liau index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Liau_index) to find out the article's readability level.

I think I have a pretty solid program with the help online but I don't know why some of the errors are happening in the link below. 
https://submit.cs50.io/check50/35e7ae7e4b968d6b06a8152f61a0e83381b376ab

For context, please see https://cs50.harvard.edu/college/psets/2/readability/

Here's the code that I am having trouble with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int letter;
int word;
int sentence;


int main(void)
{

// prompt the user with the question

    string article = get_string("What's the article?: ");

// set the length of article

    int n = strlen(article);

// add +1 if the article starts with alphanumeric letter

    if (isalnum(article[0]))
    {
        word = 1;
    }

// count words

    for (int i = 0; i < n;  i++)
    {
        // count letters

        if (isalnum(article[i]))
        {
            letter++;
        }

        // count words

        if (i < n - 1 && isspace(article[i]) && isalnum(article[i + 1]))
        {
            word++;
        }

        // count sentences

        if (i > 0 && (article[i] == '!' || article[i] == '?' || article[i] == '.') && isalnum(article[i - 1]))
        {
            sentence++;
        }

    }

// calculate Coleman-Liau index

    int grade = 0.0588 * (100 * letter / word) - 0.296 * (100 * sentence / word) - 15.8;

// debugger

    printf("Letters: %i\n Words: %i\n Sentences: %i\n", letter, word, sentence);

// print result
    if (grade <= 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (grade < 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", grade);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, I can't see why some of the results are skewed.

Comment: @ryyker Yes I am being coerced into using `get_string()` from `cs50`. Unfortunately it's really a challenge to describe the problem since the error messages aren't evident. In fact, I have no problem running the program but it's in the result of the program.

Comment: Take a look at _[this question and answer(s)](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/week-1-get-int-get-string-errors)_.  Take note also the site that it is posted on.  I did not realize `cs50` has its own _[dedicated place to ask](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/tour)_ questions.  You may have better luck posting this question there.  The question is not exactly a match to what you are looking for, but the site is much more aligned with `cs50` than this one.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the grade as an int. You need to round the grade so that it rounds to the nearest whole number. That should fix the issues.

Comment: I agree that you have to be careful mixing `int` and `double` because of the implicit conversions, (and that may be the the problem,) but I don't know what you mean by rounding; `int` *is* a whole number.

Comment: Wouldn't storing in an int just eliminate the decimals? For example a result of 3.68 will be 3?

Comment: I see what you mean, now: round the `double` expression and cast it into `int grade`. In addition, for example, `100 * letter / word` will be integer division, OP probably meant `100.0` (probably a minor point, in this case, since it's scaled up, it can't make more than 1% difference.) I checked out the assignment, and they do say to round, so this is probably the advice I would give, too.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the round() problem, there are two more problems with this line of code "if (i < n - 1 && isspace(article[i]) && isalnum(article[i + 1]))".

First, you didn't consider the situation in which the next word started with " or '. The latter two are not alphanumeric.

Second, suppose someone accidentally typed in more spaces between two words, this line of code wouldn't get the word count right. The CS50 assignment does require to consider such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a number of mistakes. for instance, how can your 'for loop' count the number of letters without counting spaces, commas, exclamation mark....?

second what does this mean?

```
    "if (i < n - 1 && isspace(article[i]) && isalnum(article[i + 1]))"???
```

I think this is wrong.
By the way if you want to count the number of words, it is just enough you to know the number of spaces. Then you know that:

words= space +1.

Answer (score 0):

I myself took an easier version of this, so here is one version:

```
def count_letters(text):
    num_letters = 0
    for letter in text:
        if letter.isalpha():
            num_letters += 1 
    return num_letters

def count_words(text):
    num_words = 1
    space = [' ']
    for word in text:
        if word in space:
            num_words += 1 
    return num_words

def count_sentences(text):
    num_sentences = 0
    punctuation = ['.', '!', '?']
    for sentence in text:
        if sentence in punctuation:
            num_sentences += 1 
    return num_sentences


text = input("Text: ")

letters = count_letters(text)
words = count_words(text)
sentences = count_sentences(text)

index = 0
L = letters / words * 100
S = sentences / words * 100
index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8
index = round(index)

if index < 0:
    print("Before Grade 1")
if index > 0 and index < 16:
    print(f"Grade {index}")
if index > 15:
    print("Grade 16+")
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it was broken up and came with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You must, for example, multiply by 100.000 to cast to float.
One another tip is to consider increment word at the end of the loop that runs the article chars.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};


//analyse letters, words, sentences
void analyse_text(string text);

//compute grade
int compute_grade(int letters, int words, int sentences);


int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    analyse_text(text);
}


void analyse_text(string text)
{

    int grade = 0;
    int letters = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int sentences = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        char lower_char = tolower(text[i]);

        if ('a' <=  lower_char && lower_char <= 'z')
        {
            letters++;
        }
        else if(lower_char == ' ')
        {
            words++;
        }
        else if (lower_char == '.' || lower_char == '!' || lower_char == '?')
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }
    words++;

    grade = compute_grade(letters, words, sentences);

    if (0 < grade && grade < 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", grade);
    }
    else if (grade < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }

}

// calculate grade: grade = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8
int compute_grade(int letters, int words, int sentences)
{
    float L = 100.0000 * letters / words;
    float S = 100.0000 * sentences / words;

    float f =  0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
    //printf("index: %f", f);
    return (int) round(f);
}
```